# How to associate an image node with taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, nodes

I know this is going to be a very easy answer, but I've been trying to build on someone else's code and am frustrated as hell. I need to link an image type node with a taxonomy term (or a couple terms) for categorizing them. The table is term_node and I just need to know how this table is populated, and how I can link a node (nid) with a term (tid).

When I go to mysite.com/categories/tags/tag_name I can view image nodes linked with that taxonomy term, but there was never a good interface built to add them and I'm not sure how they where added before. His code is a mess. I believe he may have used the Image Assist module, but I'm not sure.

I thought I should just be able to set the taxonomy when adding an image, but there is no such option when adding or editing the node.

Answer (score 1):

why don´t you use the [taxonomy image](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image) module
then simply get the taxonomy id from the node (use node_load(nid) then identify with var_dump how can you refer to the taxonomy..he might be using the CCK or the taxonomy module ) then get the id(s) of the term, load that term with and see it´s image (again use var_dump to know it´s structure)

Comment: Thanks, and maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how that helps. I did a var dump, but there's no useful information there. All I really need to know how to do is add an association between nid and tid on the term_node table in the Drupal frontend. I can do it in code, but I know there has to be some way to do it in Drupal.